# Split a trained neural network to 2 parts and use the latter part

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

I have a simple autoencoder DNN with 4 convolution layers followed by 4 deconvolution layers.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as lays

conv1 = lays.conv2d(inputs, 64, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
conv2 = lays.conv2d(conv1, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
conv3 = lays.conv2d(conv2, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
conv4 = lays.conv2d(conv3, 100, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')  #shape (None,1,1,100)

dconv1 = lays.conv2d_transpose(conv4, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
dconv2 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv1, 32, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
dconv3 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv2, 64, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
dconv4 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv3, 1, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh) #shape (64,64,1)
```

Here the inputs are (64,64) gray-scaled images and the autoencoder reconstructs the same input image at the output layer(dconv4).

Please note that the objective of this autoencoder is not to do segmentation, but to represent a (64x64) image as a (1,1,100) shaped unique tensor with a minimum loss.

As you can see, the shape of the conv4 tensor is (None,1,1,100), which is what I want.

After training, this autoencoder works fine for test images.

However, I am interested in splitting the trained DNN to convolution and deconvolution parts, take the deconvolution part, input my own (None,1,1,100) tensor to the dconv1 layer and observe the output at dconv4.

How do I feed my own input to a tensor in the middle of a neural network (conv4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider replacing

```
dconv1 = lays.conv2d_transpose(conv4, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
```

with a [placeholder_with_default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default) like this:

```
latent_ph = tf.placeholder_with_default(conv4, [None, 1, 1, 100], name="latent_ph")
dconv1 = lays.conv2d_transpose(latent_ph, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
```

This way, you will automatically use conv4, but you can switch it to a different input when you want by passing a feed dict to the `session.run` call when you need it to be something else:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    my_latent = np.random.random((10, 1, 1, 100))
    result = sess.run(dconv4, feed_dict={latent_ph: my_latent})
```

If you do not want to retrain, you have to load the weights from your checkpoint and assign them to the new graph with the placeholder. Something similar is done [here](https://innerpeace-wu.github.io/2017/12/13/Tensorflow-Restore-partial-weights/)

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Didn't know that we could feed tensors in the middle of a neural network. tf.placeholder_with_default() such a cool feature. Edited the question.